# I getting limited record from table

Tags: java, jdbc, resultset

How to get first 40 records from table , where i am using resultset in java and is that possible to get first 40 and next 40 and etc, where i am not using paggination.

Comment: Please be more specific. What database (MySQL/Oracle/etc) are you using and what exactly is the pagination restriction or requirement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think You are looking for pagination and every page contains 40 data item.

Query would be like -

```
select *
 from
  ( select rownum rnm, a.*
     from (your_query) a
     where rownum <= :M )
 where rnm >= :N;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not a good idea to extract *some* records from result set from performance perspective as it will load entire table data everytime. It will be good if you fire the pagination queries to load only required data (syntax is dependent on database e.g MySql provides `Limit` clause).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what exactly your question is. But if I understand you correctly, you need to get only 40 records from the DB at a time, and fetch batches of 40 records each, as and when needed.

If above is true, then you can use [CachedRowSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/sql/rowset/CachedRowSet.html). In this, you can set the size of the batch using **setPageSize()**.

If this is not what you want, please add more explanation to your question.